# Is するということであります speaking in the past, or present?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This is from a commercial for [Hermie Hopperhead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzS2MSkbvh4):

> 長官:大変お待たせいたしました。
>
> それでは、現時点で分かっている事実を発表いたします。
>
> まず、名前はハーミーホッパーヘッド。
>
> 記者A:すいません。もう一度お願いいたします。
>
> 長官:ハーミーホッパーヘッド。全部カタカナです。
>
> エ、これが、ある惑星から脱出するということであります。

Translation

> Secretary: Thank you very much for your patience.
>
> Now, let me announce the facts that are known at this time.
>
> First, it's name is Hermie Hopperhead.
>
> Reporter A: I'm sorry, could you repeat that again?
>
> Secretary: Hermie Hopperhead. The name is all in katakana.

My question is below, above was context:

So, basically, what we know is, they've escaped from some planet.

or

So, basically, what we know is, they're trying to escape from some planet.

Answer (score 2):

～であります is a polite version of ～である, which is a stiffer version of だ. ～ということだ is "It is that ～" used to give an explanation. Put together, ～ということであります translates to just "It is that ～". (As a free translation, "basically, what we know is, ..." is not wrong in this context, though.)

The remaining part is easy. Since 脱出する is in its dictionary form, it's a description of something at preset or in the future.

> これが、ある惑星から脱出するということであります。
>
> So this is going to escape from a certain planet.

At the end of this ad, the audience notice this is all about a new video game title. After knowing this, the above sentence starts to sound like "So this game is about Hermie Hopperhead trying to escape from a certain planet".

Comment: I could not have asked for a better reply. Thanks for the help!